# Rails 3: How to return errors in a JSON request?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, api

How can I return a 800, 404, etc error when a user makes a JSON/XML request to my API?

I've tried

```
error 404, {:error => "ERror".to_json }
```

with no success.

Also, I've tried to put a "respond_to" but it doesn't work as well (it duplicates the respond_to and gives error).

Thanks

Comment: can you show some code, I don't understand what you mean with the duplicate respond_to

Comment: I've never heard of http code 800 ;)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The same way you return such errors with html, it's part of the HTTP Header.

```
render json: @myobject, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

---

Update, response to comment:

You can get all the status codes from Rack. Rails passes the symbolized status to Rack

```
Rack::Utils.status_code(options[:status])
```

which simply matches the symbol to the list of status (the strings are converted to symbols)
Here is the smoking fresh list: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L575-L638

Scroll a bit lower and you'll see the `status_code` method. It's fun to read the source code!

Comment: Where can I get a list of all those :status? Thanks

Comment: The list has gone down to https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L539

Comment: You don't need to call `to_json` on the object that you send downstream. `render` calls that for you.

So in your example, `render :json => @myobject, :status => :unprocessable_entity` should suffice. :)

Also, here's the list of status codes:
[https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L549-L608](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L549-L608)

Comment: nice nit-picking @MT, I accepted both:) I also changed to newer syntax, abandoning hashrockets